# How to correctly use batch deletein VSCode with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using a firebase trigger function to delete a collection when a certain document is deleted,
So far my function works great the trigger is activated when a document is deleted and I get the data I need to get the path to the collection i want deleted.
I use forEach to go through all the documents and put them in a batch delete then commit the Batch.

The very first time this function is triggered it works perfectly the document is deleted I get a path to the collection then all documents are put into the batch delete and then committed

After that though the problem I'm having is if a second time another document is deleted, I get the path to the collection and then in the fourEach statement it loops through the collection only once and then it goes to the catch block.

I don't understand what's going on why it's not working I've tried this multiple times and I'm getting the same error

I commented the batch delete and commit and tried the below line of code and the function works great every time it's called,
all the documents are deleted in the collection, so I know its something to do with how i'm implementing batch but i have no idea what's wrong

```
        //db.collection(`messages/${currentuid}/${contex.documentId}`).doc(document.id).delete()
```

My full code is

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const batch = db.batch();

//triggers when a document is deleted 

exports.onDeletCollections = functions.firestore.document('recentMsg/{currentuid}/{touid}/{documentId}').onDelete(async(snap, context) => {

const data = snap.data();

//extract the users uid from the document that was deleted 
const currentuid = data['fromuid']

const contex = context.params;


await db.collection(`messages/${currentuid}/${contex.documentId}`).get()
.then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(document => {

            if (snapshot.size === 0) {
                console.log(` The snapshot size Should be zero if the if block works ${snapshot.size}`)
                return
            }

// below line works fine every time it's called but not batch
        //db.collection(`messages/${currentuid}/${contex.documentId}`).doc(document.id).delete()

           batch.delete(db.collection(`messages/${uid}/${contex.documentId}`).doc(document.id))
        });
        batch.commit()
    })
    .then(
      console.log(`Do whatever you wish after the batch has been committed`)
    )
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(` This is being printed from the catch block `) 
    });

});
```

This is my first week on Firebase functions I'm very new at this so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a Promise when all the asynchronous job is completed. See this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details on this key point. Also, it is better not to mix-up `then()` and `async/await`.

The following should therefore do the trick:

```
exports.onDeletCollections = functions.firestore.document('recentMsg/{currentuid}/{touid}/{documentId}').onDelete(async (snap, context) => {

    const currentuid = snap.get('fromuid');
    const context = context.params;

    const snapshot = await db.collection(`messages/${currentuid}/${context.documentId}`).get();

    if (snapshot.size === 0) {
        console.log(` The snapshot size Should be zero if the if block works ${snapshot.size}`)
        return null;
    } else {

        const batch = db.batch();
        snapshot.forEach(document => {
            batch.delete(db.collection(`messages/${uid}/${context.documentId}`).doc(document.id))
        });
        return batch.commit();  // See the return here!!
    }

});
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback I upvoted but as a newbie reputation is below 15 so can't  be registered

Comment: No problem :-) You may accept the answer, see https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=stackoverflow+someone+answers. Thx.